# R graph not displaying correctly

Tags: r

I have a graph below and I am wondering why things on the graph are not showing up properly?

```
time<- as.POSIXct(c("2014-12-10 20:51:53.103","2014-12-10 20:56:54.204"), tz= "GMT")
p<-c(49.32, 60)
s<-c("B","")
pointcolor<-c("red","black")
share<-c(35,0)
pointsize<-c(1.01,1)
shapeType<-c(16,10)
bigDF<-data.frame(time=time, p=p, s=s, pointcolor=pointcolor, share=share, pointsize=pointsize, shapeType=shapeType)
bigDF
ggplot(bigDF, aes(x=time, y=p)) + geom_line() + geom_point( aes(shape = as.factor(shapeType),size = pointsize, color = pointsize))
```

When you run that you should see the first point red but it is showing up as a turqoise. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

That's because of the default palette that ggplot uses for the discrete colour scale. You can change that like this:

```
ggplot(bigDF, aes(x=time, y=p)) + 
  geom_point( aes(shape = as.factor(shapeType),size = pointsize, color = pointcolor)) 
  scale_color_manual(values = levels(bigDF$pointcolor))
```

where

```
levels(bigDF$pointcolor)
[1] "black" "red"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplot(bigDF, aes(x=time, y=p)) + 
 geom_line() + 
 geom_point(aes(shape = as.factor(shapeType)),size = pointsize, color = pointcolor)
```

will sort you. You put the color parameter inside the aes call.